# angular 6 ng-select startsWith instead of Contains

Tags: angular, select, angular6

I am using `ng-select` and I want the search function to work with StartsWith and not Contains.

But I can't fire up the (search) event. I can bind to `[searchFn]` but I don't exactly know if that's the correct approach.

Comment: Please show us what you have done.

Answer (score 4):

I fixed it by using `[searchFn]="onSearch()"` in the html and with this code in ts file:

```
public onSearch(word: string, item: { id: number, name: string }): boolean {
    return item.name.toLocaleLowerCase().startsWith(word.toLocaleLowerCase())
}
```

Comment: didn't know the searchFn iterates through every option. 
[this](https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select/blob/master/demo/app/examples/search.component.ts) is a good example in the ng-select documentation